# What is the difference between np.linspace and np.arange?

Tags: python, numpy, range, linspace

I have always used `np.arange`. I recently came across `np.linspace`. I am wondering what exactly is the difference between them... Looking at their documentation:

[`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.

[`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.

The only difference I can see is `linspace` having more options... Like choosing to include the last element.

Which one of these two would you recommend and why? And in which cases is `np.linspace` superior?

Comment: arange allow you to define the size of the step. linspace allow you to define the number of steps.

Comment: `linspace(0,1,20)`: 20 evenly spaced numbers from 0 to 1 (inclusive). `arange(0, 10, 2)`: however many numbers are needed to go from 0 to 10 (exclusive) in steps of 2.

Comment: The big difference is that one uses a `step` value, the other a `count`.  `arange` follows the behavior of the python `range`, and is best for creating an array of integers.  It's docs recommend `linspace` for floats.

Comment: Its quite clear with parameter names: `np.linspace(start=0,stop=1,num=5)` and `np.arange(start=0,stop=1,step=0.25)`.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`np.linspace` allows you to define how many values you get including the specified min and max value. It infers the stepsize:

```py
>>> np.linspace(0,1,11)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

`np.arange` allows you to define the stepsize and infers the number of steps(the number of values you get).

```py
>>> np.arange(0,1,.1)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
```

---

contributions from [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica):

`np.arange` excludes the maximum value unless rounding error makes it do otherwise.

For example, the following results occur due to rounding error:

```py
>>> numpy.arange(1, 1.3, 0.1)
array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
```

You can exclude the `stop` value (in our case 1.3) using `endpoint=False`:

```py
>>> numpy.linspace(1, 1.3, 3, endpoint=False)
array([1. , 1.1, 1.2])
```

Comment: "It excludes the maximum value" - unless rounding error makes it do otherwise, so stick with `linspace`. You can specify `endpoint=False` if you want to exclude the right endpoint with `linspace`.

Comment: For example, `numpy.arange(1, 1.3, 0.1)` gives `array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])` due to rounding error, while `numpy.linspace(1, 1.3, 3, endpoint=False)` gives `array([1. , 1.1, 1.2])`.

Comment: @user2357112 agreed. See edits to my post (and feel free to edit)

Answer (score 6):

`numpy.linspace` and `numpy.arange` can produce two variables that appear the same but aren't. This must be related to how data is stored internally. When I created ndarrays using `arange`, the size in the memory scaled with the number of elements. However, the `ndarray` created using `linspace` remained the same size.

```py
from sys import getsizeof
import numpy as np
arr_lnspc5 = np.linspace(1,5,5)
arr_lnspc20 = np.linspace(1,20,20)
arr_arange5 = np.arange(1,6,1.0)
arr_arange20 = np.arange(1,21,1.0)

print(f'lnspc5   ==============')
print(f'Val: {arr_lnspc5}')
print(f'Type: {type(arr_lnspc5)}')
print(f'Size: {getsizeof(arr_lnspc5)} Bytes \n')

print(f'lnspc20  ==============')
print(f'Val: {arr_lnspc20}')
print(f'Type: {type(arr_lnspc20)}')
print(f'Size: {getsizeof(arr_lnspc20)} Bytes \n')

print(f'arange5  ==============')
print(f'Val: {arr_arange5}')
print(f'Type: {type(arr_arange5)}')
print(f'Size: {getsizeof(arr_arange5)} Bytes \n')

print(f'arange20 ==============')
print(f'Val: {arr_arange20}')
print(f'Type: {type(arr_arange20)}')
print(f'Size: {getsizeof(arr_arange20)} Bytes \n')
```

The output I got was:

```
lnspc5   ==============
Val: [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Size: 112 Bytes 

lnspc20  ==============
Val: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20.]
Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Size: 112 Bytes 

arange5  ==============
Val: [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Size: 152 Bytes 

arange20 ==============
Val: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20.]
Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Size: 272 Bytes
```

Comment: This is incredibly important if you are concerned about scientific computing such as machine learning where you are concerned about multipling things by a learning rate and constantly updating weights. If you aren't careful about dtype of an array, you might come across the issue of overflow and get an 'NaN'. If you do any operation with an 'NaN', you get an 'NaN'. In other words, if at some point, there is an 'NaN' in the sequence of weights, the final weight is 'NaN', which could be a let down and confusing after you leave the computer running for two hours. Good point!

Answer (score 5):

```
np.arange(start, stop, step)
np.linspace(start,stop,number)
```

Example:

```
np.arange(0,10,2)    o/p --> array([0,2,4,6,8])
np.linspace(0,10,2)  o/p --> array([0., 10.])
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange` - This is similar to built in `range()` function

```
>>> np.arange(0,5,2)
[0 2 4]
```

`np.linpace` - creates an array of defined evenly spaced value. For example, 2 values evenly spaced between 0 and 5

```
>>> np.linspace(0,5,2)
[0. 5.]
```

Comment: np.linespace just throws an attribute error because there is no such function.