# Numpy linspace function stop value

Tags: python, function, numpy, include, linspace

I giving start and stop values as parameters to the linspace function
Stop value is normally does not include in the array. Because of this we always write [stop+1] in order to make include the stop value.
But in linspace, if i write

```
np.linspace(0, 20, 5)
```

the output is:

```
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Why linspace function output includes the stop value when arange function does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from Numpy [linspace documnetation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)
Parameter

> **endpoint : bool**, optional
> If True, stop is the last sample. Otherwise, it is not included. **Default is True**.

as explained nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106028/what-is-the-difference-between-np-linspace-and-np-arange) the 2 functions are similar with slightly different approaches -

- *linspace's* goal is to give us a list of values equally spaced between the start point and endpoint, the only required parameter (except for the start/end) is how many items do we want. Therefore the end considers a legitimate item in that list.
- *arrange's*  goal is to give a list of steps according to the stepsize parameter we gave it. we're handling the steps so I guess the end doesn't concern us
  this is my two cents for this issue...